# Combining rewrites for non-www/ssl/trailing slash with upper->lowercase in .htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

So I have a straightforward rewrite to catch non-www URLs, non-SSL urls and urls missing a trailing slash to redirect to SSL, www and trailing slash using:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)$  [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*[^/])$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*\/)$ https://www.tierpoint/$1 [R=301,L] 
RewriteRule (.*[^/])$ https://www.tierpoint/$1/ [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

I'd like to add a rewrite to drive uppercase requests to lowercase (sparing anything in a query string)

I know I can loop througRewriteRule [A-Z] - [E=HASCAPS:TRUE,S=1]

```
RewriteRule ![A-Z] - [S=28]
RewriteRule ^([^A]*)A(.*)$ $1a$2
...RewriteRule ^([^Z]*)Z(.*)$ $1z$2
RewriteRule [A-Z] - [N]
RewriteCond %{ENV:HASCAPS} TRUE
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) /$1 [R=301,L]
```

But how can I combine these?

Comment: As per [this meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283057/mod-rewrite-questions-getting-migrated-to-sf) and [this meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283033/are-htaccess-questions-ever-on-topic-at-so) this question is not at all off-topic for SO so close vote is wrong. This has been discussed again and again and it has been settled already that most of the rewrite rules are created and maintained by developers of the web applications/frameworks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have it like this in your site root .htaccess:

```sh
RewriteEngine On

# add www, https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI}  [R=301,L,NE]

# add a trailing slash is query string is not present
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^[^.]+?[^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301,NE]

# convert URI to lowercase
# This requires Apache 2.4
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond expr "tolower(%{REQUEST_URI}) =~ m#(.+)#"
RewriteRule [A-Z] %1 [L,NE,R=301]
```

Comment: sorry, I've been offline, this worked exactly how I needed. Thank you