# Creating rewrite that excludes adding trailing slash before query string or at the end of a file name in htaaccess

Tags: .htaccess

Here are the current rules I have:

```
RewriteEngine On

# add www, https, trailing slash
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ https://www.%1/$1/ [R=301,L,NE]

# convert URI to lowercase
# This requires Apache 2.4
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond expr "tolower(%{REQUEST_URI}) =~ m#(.+)#"
RewriteRule [A-Z] %1 [L,NE,R=301]
```

However, I need to avoid adding a trailing slash either preceding a query string OR at the end of a query string or when the request has a file type at the end (e.g. .pdf, .js, .png, etc.)

I've tried to modify this RewriteConds to exclude URLs that include a query string and a "." from having a trailing slash added, but I don't seem to be able to trap

Comment: If you're using my [suggested answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65102083/548225) then you should first mark that as accepted

Comment: btw you can add `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$` as first condition to avoid affecting a URL with query string.